# Switching between two appliances on a single power socket

Tags: electrical, switch, socket, extension

Is there a device on which I can plug in 2 appliances, however with a button/switch, I can switch between these two appliances so only one is active at a time?

I don’t want to plug and unplug appliances multiple times.

Comment: What kind of appliances are we talking about - a toaster & a coffee maker or a clothes dryer and an oven? Where in the world are you? What kind of power supply do you have (110v or 240v)?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Are these "always on" appliances that don't have their own power switches so the only way to turn them off is to unplug them? (At my house, those are called "Internet modem", "router", and "network switch", and I prefer that they remain on all the time, but I'm guessing that's _not_ what you're talking about.)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps?  Your question is somewhat ambiguous but this sort of independently controlled power strip appears to meet the requirement:

[image]

Comment: In my understanding the OP wants a switch that enforces that both of two appliances cannot be on at the same time.

Comment: though we're still not sure why

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends upon power demands of the "appliances".  If they have high power needs like a clothes dryer, water heater, electric range, air conditioner, etc. that would be a different approach than simpler 120v appliances.   You'll need to source a switch with the correct rating.   Also, heavy duty appliances would need to have similar power requirements.   I assume you want to do this because you have very limited electrical supply? Off grid solar? or in your country, very limited power?

Here is a starting point.   You'll want to consider local code compliance where you are as well.   [image: high power DPDT switch]